# Realm-Android: field value and field getter value are not the same

Tags: android, realm

```
public class MessageBean extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private int read;

    public int getRead() {
        return read;
    }

    public void setRead(int read) {
        this.read = read;
    }
}
```

getter

[Field Getter Value debug Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEYWA.png)

field
[Field Value debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/991hx.png)

Comment: What version of Realm are you using?

Comment: the version is 1.2.0

Comment: Interesting, is this method inside a constructor of a class that extends RealmObject?

Comment: No constructors,just a sample bean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the direct field access in your case is not transformed at this time.

You would get proper result if you change your current code:

```
realm.where(MessageBean.class)
     .equalTo("userId", PreferenceUtils.getUserId(UIUtils.getContext()))
     .or()
     .equalTo("userId", PreferenceUtils.STRING_DEFAULT)
     .equalTo("type", PushType.PERSONAL_ACTIVITY)
     .or()
     .equalTo("type", PushType.ARTICLE)
     .equalTo("read", 0)
     .findAll()
     .get(0)
     .read
```

with

```
RealmResults<MessageBean> results = realm.where(MessageBean.class)
     .beginGroup()
     .equalTo("userId", PreferenceUtils.getUserId(UIUtils.getContext()))
     .endGroup()
     .or()
     .beginGroup()
     .equalTo("userId", PreferenceUtils.STRING_DEFAULT)
     .equalTo("type", PushType.PERSONAL_ACTIVITY)
     .endGroup()
     .or()
     .beginGroup()
     .equalTo("type", PushType.ARTICLE)
     .equalTo("read", 0)
     .endGroup()
     .findAll();
 MessageBean message = results.get(0);
 int result = message.read; // <-- will return proper value
```

So you should store the `results.get(0)` first into a local variable, that way the `Realm-Transformer` will be able to detect it. (although to be fair, I think it *should* work even without this trick).

If you use Accessor method, then it uses the proxy accessor even without the Realm-Transformer running through this line of code.

It is key that in the debugger, you check for the obtained value, and not the field value in the object itself.

Comment: You do have `instant run` disabled, right? If this is not a RealmObject's constructor, then it should work with Realm 1.2.0.

Comment: You need to make sure you are adding watcher for value of `result`, and **not** for `message.read`